# Execute a function and use the output later in my script without calling the function again - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to execute a function and use the output later in my script without calling the function again.
I'm trying to use the output of deal().

```
let playersHand = ["Ace of Clubs", "6 of Hearts"];

function deal(){
  let cardPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()*(shuffledDeck.length));
  dealCard = shuffledDeck.splice(cardPosition, 1);
  return dealCard;
}
function allOfPlayersCards(){
  let playersCards = playersHand.concat(deal);
  console.log(playersCards)
}

The Console Output is ["Ace of Clubs", "6 of Hearts", ƒ]
```

If I do deal() it executes deal again, and I use deal the output just says 'f'.

Thank you, sorry if this is obvious I'm pretty new to coding.

Comment: You are `concat`ing the function `deal` instead of calling it, e.g. `deal()`

Comment: Call the function, store the result in a variable, and use/reuse the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the result of `deal()` on a variable and reuse the variable instead of calling it again (unless if you want to do calculation again)

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenation the functions, don't the value returned to him. you can change the moment of the concatenation to `.concat(deal())`, thus you are concatenation the value return of the `deal`

exemplo:

```
let playersHand = ["Ace of Clubs", "6 of Hearts"];

function deal(){
  let cardPosition = Math.floor(Math.random()*(shuffledDeck.length));
  dealCard = shuffledDeck.splice(cardPosition, 1);
  return dealCard;
}
function allOfPlayersCards(){
  let playersCards = playersHand.concat(deal());
  console.log(playersCards)
}

The Console Output is ["Ace of Clubs", "6 of Hearts", <value-returned-from-deal>]
```